# Pattern matching parser

Tags: java, regex, parsing

Actually, I built a Java code to parse the following text file:

```
     (FAMIX.Attribute (id: 22)
(name 'obj_I')
(parentType (ref: 11))
(declaredType (ref: 27))
(isPrivate true)
   )

   (FAMIX.Attribute (id: 38)
(name 'obj_k')
(parentType (ref: 34))
(declaredType (ref: 43))
(isPrivate true)
   )

  (FAMIX.Attribute (id: 56)
(name 'obj_K')
(parentType (ref: 46))
(declaredType (ref: 43))
(isPrivate true)
    )

  (FAMIX.Attribute (id: 73)
(name 'obj_L')
(parentType (ref: 64))
(declaredType (ref: 45))
(isPrivate true)
    )

 (FAMIX.Attribute (id: 67)
(name 'obj_G')
(parentType (ref: 64))
(declaredType (ref: 46))
(isPrivate true)
    )

 (FAMIX.Attribute (id: 93)
(name 'classD')
(parentType (ref: 85))
(declaredType (ref: 94))
(isPrivate true)
   )

  (FAMIX.Attribute (id: 99)
(name 'classC')
(parentType (ref: 86))
(declaredType(ref: 86))
(isPackage true)
    )

 (FAMIX.Attribute (id: 114)
(name 'classB')
(parentType (ref: 94))
(declaredType (ref: 11))
(isPrivate true)
    )

  (FAMIX.Attribute (id: 107)
(name 'obj_c')
(parentType (ref: 94))
(declaredType (ref: 86))
(isPrivate true)
     )
```

The Java code:

```
// Find Attributes

Pattern p111 = Pattern.compile("FAMIX.Attribute");

Matcher m111 = p111.matcher(line);
while (m111.find()) {

    FAMIXAttribute obj = new FAMIXAttribute();              
    Pattern p222 = Pattern.compile("id:\\s*([0-9]+)");
    Matcher m222 = p222.matcher(line);

    while (m222.find()) {
        System.out.print(m222.group(1));
    }

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !(line.contains("FAMIX"))) {

        Pattern p333 = Pattern.compile("name\\s*'([\\w]+)\\s*'");
        Matcher m333 = p333.matcher(line);

        while (m333.find()) {       

            System.out.print(m333.group(1));
        }

        Pattern p555 = Pattern.compile("parentType\\s*\\(ref:\\s*([0-9]+)\\)");
        Matcher m555 = p555.matcher(line);
        while (m555.find()) {
           System.out.print(m555.group(1));
        }

        Pattern p666 =   Pattern.compile("declaredType\\s*\\(ref:\\s*([0-9]+)\\)");
        Matcher m666 = p666.matcher(line);
        while (m666.find()) {
           System.out.print(m666.group(1));
        } 

    }

} // exit from finding Attribute
```

The output:

```
     ***************** Attributes *****************
       obj_k    38   34   43
       obj_L    73   64   45
       classD   93   85   94
       classB   114  94   11
```

Based on the output, the problem is the parser skip some output (jump)

Please let me know if the problem is unclear, and I will try to further clarify it.

Comment: The problem is when the `line` contains `FAMIX`, you didn't save the `line` for the next run, therefore it skips over some group.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the regex to check for the `IsPrivate` or `IsPackage` part

Edit:
A few steps will tell you what went wrong
Add a printout of the line to see exactly what lines are failing and how the Pattern sees them

```
     // Find Attributes
                System.out.print("***"+line+"***"); 
                Pattern p111 = Pattern.compile("FAMIX.Attribute");
                Matcher m111 = p111.matcher(line);
                while (m111.find()) {
```

The `"***"` will give you a sense of the exact beginning and end of the line, regarding java.
Sometimes characters that seem identical to the eye are different for the matcher.

Edit 2:
Your code is missing the outer loop, where line gets its first read.
Do you realize that the code:

```
                  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !(line.contains("FAMIX"))) {
```

consumes the next line where "FAMIX.Attribute" appears? If you do another read in the (missing) outer loop, you will be missing every other record.

Comment: i dont want to read this information ,, i need just the name + id + parenttype+ declaredtype

Comment: still have the same problem .

Comment: same problem , it still skipping

Comment: yes , it is a large text file , I’m trying to read many information from the same text file

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the file contains the lines in the exact format as specified:

- Each of `id`, `name`, `parentType`, `declaredType` must be fully declared on a single line. i.e. you don't have such input:

  ```
  (FAMIX.Attribute (id:
  38)
  (name 
  'obj_k')
  (parentType 
    (ref: 34))
  (declaredType (ref: 43))
  (isPrivate true)
  )
  ```

  But this is allowed:

  ```
  (FAMIX.Attribute (id: 38)
  (name 'obj_k') (parentType (ref: 34)) (declaredType (ref: 43)) (isPrivate true))
  ```

This is the pre-condition for *the modification below* to work. **This assumption is derived from your current code.**

```
String line;

FAMIXAttribute obj = new FAMIXAttribute();
boolean isModified = false;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.contains("FAMIX.Attribute")) {
        if (isModified) {
            // TODO: Save the previous obj

            obj = new FAMIXAttribute();
            isModified = false;
        } 
    }

    // TODO: Add the block of code to parse id here
    // TODO: Add id attribute to obj, set isModified to true

    // TODO: Add the block of code to parse other stuffs here
    // TODO: Add those attributes to obj, set isModified to true
}

if (isModified) {
    // TODO: Save the last obj
}
```